# Significance of partial derivatives in the conversion of unit vectors from Cartesian to Cylindrical Co-ordinate system

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

I was watching a video on the conversion of cartesian unit vectors to cylindrical unit vectors.

I understood till the point where he said
$$
\vec r = r \cos\phi \, \hat\imath_x 
+ r \sin\phi \, \hat \imath_y + z \, \hat z 
$$

and then he went ahead and partially differentiated $\vec r$ by $r$ to get the unit vector in the direction of $r$ and partially differentiated $\vec r$ by $\phi$ to get the unit vector in the direction of $\phi$.

Why was this partial differentiation done? He explained it was to find the unit vector in the direction of the increase of the parameter.

Is this like a directional derivative where you take a gradient of the scalar function and then take the dot product of the gradient with the unit vector direction in which you want to find the derivative?

Comment: Note: `\cos` gives the cosine function, set in roman (upright) style, and `\imath` produces $\imath$ without the dot so you can more easily fit a hat on top: $\hat\imath$.

Comment: Thank you @Sammy Black

Comment: Partial derivatives *are* directional derivatives in the direction of the coordinate wrt which we differentiate.

Comment: But what does the partial derivate in the conversion above yield? What is the idea behind it?